# Share SSH Session at login

Tags: ssh, remote-x-session

Hi there im trying to give some support for a co-workers im making a reverse ssh tunnel from remote machine to one of my cloud servers.

I want to control remote machine with the reverse tunnel but at the same time to share the session to the remote user so they can see what im doing buy i want to do this automatically when i login to the reverse connection.

is there away to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `screen` command to share the session.

Login to the server and create the screen with a specific session name

`screen -L -S MySharedScreen`

Then the other guy can ssh into the machine and join the session like this:

`screen -x MySharedScreen`

Answer (score 0):

https://nutty.io is a tool to share SSH-terminal sessions. Your colleague can use this to SSH into a machine and give you the unique URL that nutty provides. You can use that URL to collaborate on the terminal with your colleague.